# Binomial cumulative distribution function and the regularized incomplete beta function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, probability-distributions

In wikipedia, [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution), it is mention that $\sum_{i=0}^x \binom{n}{i} p^i(1-p)^{n-i} = I_{1-p}(n-x,x+1)$ where $\sum_{i=0}^x \binom{n}{i} p^i(1-p)^{n-i}$ is the binomial cumulative distribution function and $I_{1-p}(n-x,x+1)$ is the regularized incomplete beta function with $p \in [0,1]$, $n \geq x \geq 0$, $n \in \mathbb{N}^*$ and $x \in \mathbb{N}^*$. Taking into account these definitions I have the following:

$$\begin{split}
  F(x;n,p) & = \mathbf{P}(X \leq x) \\
  & = \sum_{i=0}^x \binom{n}{i} p^i(1-p)^{n-i} \\
  & = I_{1-p}(n-x,x+1) \\
  & = 1 - I_p(x+1,n-x) \\
  & = 1 - \frac{\beta(p;x+1,n-x)}{\beta(x+1,n-x)} \\
  & = 1 - \frac{\Gamma(x+1+n-x)}{\Gamma(x+1)\Gamma(n-x)} \int_0^p t^x(1-t)^{n-x-1} dt \\
  \end{split}$$

Let's see for example $p=0$. In the case of $F(x;n,0) = 0$ but in the case of $I_{1-0}(n-x,x+1) = 1$ so $F(x;n,p) \neq I_{1-p}(n-x,x+1)$ when $p=0$. However we can restrict $p$ to $p \in (0,1]$. In the case of $p=1$ we have that $F(x;n,1) = 0$ and $I_{1-1}(n-x,x+1) = 0$ so there is no problem.

Because in wikipedia there is no proof about $\sum_{i=0}^x \binom{n}{i} p^i(1-p)^{n-i} = I_{1-p}(n-x,x+1)$ and there is a mistake when $p=0$, using what is mention [here](https://faculty.washington.edu/fscholz/DATAFILES/ConfidenceBounds.pdf) I can use the following:

$$\begin{split}
  I_{1-p}(n-x,x+1) & = 1 - I_p(x+1,n-x) \\
  & = 1 - \frac{\beta(p;x+1,n-x)}{\beta(x+1,n-x)} \\
  & = 1 - \frac{\Gamma(x+1+n-x)}{\Gamma(x+1)\Gamma(n-x)} \int_0^p t^x(1-t)^{n-x-1} dt \\
  & = 1 - \frac{n!}{x!(n-x-1)!} \int_0^p t^x(1-t)^{n-x-1} dt \\
  & = 1 - (n-x)\frac{n!}{x!(n-x)!} \int_0^p t^x(1-t)^{n-x-1} dt \\
  & = 1 - (n-x)\binom{n}{x} \int_0^p t^x(1-t)^{n-x-1} dt \\
  \frac{dI_{1-p}(n-x,x+1)}{dp} & = - (n-x)\binom{n}{x} \frac{d}{dp} \int_0^p t^x(1-t)^{n-x-1} dt \text{ by the fundamental theorem of calculus} \\
  & = - (n-x)\binom{n}{x} p^x(1-p)^{n-x-1} \\
  \end{split}$$

$$\begin{split}
  F(x;n,p) & = \mathbf{P}(X \leq x) \\
  & = \sum_{i=0}^x \binom{n}{i} p^i(1-p)^{n-i} \\
  & = \binom{n}{0} p^0(1-p)^{n-0} + \binom{n}{1} p^1(1-p)^{n-1} + \cdots + \binom{n}{x-1} p^{x-1}(1-p)^{n-(x-1)} + \binom{n}{x} p^x(1-p)^{n-x} \\
  & = \binom{n}{0} p^0(1-p)^{n-0} + \binom{n}{1} p^1(1-p)^{n-1} + \cdots + \binom{n}{x-1} p^{x-1}(1-p)^{n-(x-1)} + \binom{n}{x} p^x(1-p)^{n-x} \\
  \frac{dF(x;n,p)}{dp} & = \binom{n}{0} (n-0)p^0(1-p)^{n-1} + \binom{n}{1} (1p^{1-1}(1-p)^{n-1} - (n-1)p^1(1-p)^{n-2}) + \cdots + \\ 
  & \;\;\;\; \binom{n}{x-1} ((x-1)p^{x-2}(1-p)^{n-(x-1)} - (n-(x-1))p^{x-1}p^{n-(x-1)}) + \\
  & \;\;\;\; \binom{n}{x} (xp^{x-1}(1-p)^{n-x} - (n-x)p^x(1-p)^{n-x-1}) \\
  & = \sum_{i=1}^x \binom{n}{i} ip^{i-1}(1-p)^{n-i} - \sum_{i=0}^x \binom{n}{i}(n-i)p^i(1-p)^{n-i-1} \\
  & = n \Biggr[ \sum_{i=1}^x \binom{n-1}{i-1}p^{i-1}(1-p)^{n-i} - \sum_{i=0}^x \binom{n-1}{i}p^i(1-p)^{n-i-1} \Biggr] \text{ where } i \binom{n}{i} = n\binom{n-1}{i-1};(n-i)\binom{n}{i} = n\binom{n-1}{i} \\
  & = n \Biggr[ \sum_{i=1}^x \binom{n-1}{i-1}p^{i-1}(1-p)^{n-i} - \sum_{i=1}^x \binom{n-1}{i-1}p^{i-1}(1-p)^{n-i} - \binom{n-1}{x}p^x(1-p)^{n-x-1} \Biggr] \\  
  & = - n\binom{n-1}{x}p^x(1-p)^{n-x-1} \\
  & = - n\frac{(n-1)!}{x!(n-1-x)!}p^x(1-p)^{n-x-1} \\
  & = - (n-x)\binom{n}{x}p^x(1-p)^{n-x-1} \\
  \end{split}$$

So $\frac{dF(x;n,p)}{dp} = \frac{dI_{1-p}(n-x,x+1)}{dp}$.

But now I am stuck here because I don't know how to prove that $F(x;n,p) = I_{1-p}(n-x,x+1)$ for $p \in (0,1]$, $n \geq x \geq 0$, $n \in \mathbb{N}^*$ and $x \in \mathbb{N}^*$ in a rigorous way using the fact that $\frac{dF(x;n,p)}{dp} = \frac{dI_{1-p}(n-x,x+1)}{dp}$.